# Exercise in Just/Weese (amoeba forcing) (1/2)

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I solved the following exercise (18.3):

[image]

Can you tell me if I got it right? Thanks:

18.3.(a) The inclusion "$\supseteq$" follows immediately from the definition. For "$\subseteq$" let $U \in \mathbb A (\varepsilon)$. Then $U$ is open and $\mu(U) < \varepsilon$. Since $\mu(U \setminus F) = \mu (U) - \mu (\bigcup F)$ we can rewrite the second condition in $\mathbb A(\varepsilon)_F$ as $\mu (U) < \frac{\varepsilon + \delta_F}{2}$. We distinguish three cases:

If $\mu(U) < \varepsilon / 2$: then $U \in \mathbb A (\varepsilon)_\varnothing$.

If $\mu(U) = \varepsilon / 2$: If $B_n$ are basic open sets with $\bigcup_n B_n = U$ then pick any $B_n$ with $\mu(B_n) > 0$ and let $F = \{B_n\}$. Then $U \in \mathbb A(\varepsilon)_F$.

If $\mu(U) > \varepsilon / 2$: Again assume $B_n$ are basic open sets with $U = \bigcup B_n$. Then $\mu (B_n) \to 0$ since the sequence is absolutely convergent. Fix $n_0$ such that $\sum_{n \le n_0} \mu (B_n) \ge \frac{\mu (U) + \varepsilon / 2}{2} = K \ge \varepsilon / 2$. Then $\mu (U) < \varepsilon = \varepsilon / 2 + \varepsilon / 2 \le \varepsilon / 2 + K$. Let $n_1$ be such that  $\sum_{n \le n_0} \mu (B_n) \ge K / 2$. Then $U \in \mathbb A (\varepsilon)_{B_0, B_1, \dots, B_{n_1}}$.

---

18.3. (b): Let $U,V \in \mathbb A(\varepsilon)_F$. Then $\mu ( U \cup V) \le \mu (U \setminus \bigcup F) + \mu (\bigcup F) + \mu ( V \setminus \bigcup F) < \varepsilon$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Lucky for you there is a guy on this site with works on all sort of amoebas and creature forcings!

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think anyone with basic knowledge in measure theory would be able to proof-read this.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But who are you talking about? Arthur? Or yourself?

Comment: Probably. I was looking for a good entertainment that goes along with my breakfast. I suppose amoebas are as good as any other form of fun. :-)

Comment: I don't go much beyond Cohen forcing, because most of my forcing is used for symmetries anyway. So it's not me.

Comment: Hehe, I like how you _not_ say who. Time will give the answer : )

Comment: I was trying to build the suspense... :-)

Comment: Oh... and if anyone has the book: There is a weird sentence right after the excerpt I included above. It reads "Unfortunately, there are also much messier reasons for having the c.c.c.." Could it be that they mean to write "Unfortunately, there are also much messier conditions that imply that the c.c.c. is satisfied."?

Comment: About the "messier reasons" I think what Just/Weese are saying the following.  If a poset is $\sigma$-linked, then it is c.c.c. for a quite nice reason: writing $\mathbb{P} = \bigcup_{i < \omega} P_i$ where each $P_i$ is linked, any antichain $A \subseteq \mathbb{P}$ can contain at most one element of each $P_i$, and therefore cannot be uncountable.  But there are c.c.c. posets whose c.c.c.-ness requires (slightly) more specialised methods than just decomposing the entire poset into countably many nice subsets.  (cont...)

Comment: (...inued) The example given in the text is $\mathrm{Fn} ( \kappa , \omega )$ for $\kappa > 2^\omega$ (essentially).  But _even these_ tend to be not so terrible once you get used to them.  You apply the $\Delta$-System Lemma, and you generally end up showing that they satisfy the stronger _Knaster_ property.  (In my opinion these are closer to the _usual_ cases, so it is kind of weird to see this reason referred to as "messier".)

Comment: @ArthurFischer Thank you. You seem to agree with my interpretation of the comment. // I am not particularly fond of how this paragraph containing "messier reasons" is written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (a) you really don't have to distinguish between cases (and your third case seems needlessly complicated).  Overall I cannot find any *problems* with the proof.  Here is my solution:

> Given any nonempty $U \in \mathbb{A} (\varepsilon)$, since $U$ is open there is a sequence $\langle U_i \rangle_{i \in \omega}$ in $\mathcal{B}$ such that $U = \bigcup_{i \in \omega} U_i$.  For each $n \in \omega$ let $\delta_n = \mu_1 ( \bigcup_{i < n} U_i )$.  Since $\langle \delta_n \rangle_{n \in \omega}$ is non-decreasing with limit $\mu_1 ( U ) < \varepsilon$, there is an $n$ such that $$\mu_1 (U) - \delta_n < \varepsilon - \mu_1 ( U ),$$ but, as you have basically noted, $\mu_1 (U) = \delta_n + \mu_1 ( U \setminus {\textstyle \bigcup_{i \leq n}} U_i )$, so by rearranging we have
>   $$
> \mu_1 ( U \setminus {\textstyle \bigcup_{i < n}} U_i ) = \mu_1 ( U )  - \delta_n < \varepsilon - \mu_1 (U) = \varepsilon - \delta_n - \mu_1 ( U \setminus {\textstyle \bigcup_{i < n}} U_i ).
> $$
>   Thus $F = \{ U_i : i < n \}$ is as required.

For (b), your solution seems perfect (except to be ***pedantic*** one should note that $U \cap V$ is open).